# How to read the name of the variable at initialization and store it n a descriptor class in python?

Tags: python, python-descriptors

My plan is this: Using python descriptors, I want to read the name of the variable at assignment time.
Current code:

```py
class Decriptor:
    def __init__(self, field_type: typing.Type[typing.Any]):
        self.field_type = field_type
        self.value = None
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value
    def __set__(self, instance, constant):
        if issubclass(type(constant), self.field_type):
             self.value = constant
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"expected an instance of type {self.field_type.__name__} for attribute {}, got {type(constant).__name__} instead")
```

My reason for using descriptors is to implement static typing at compile time and to provide a wrapper for field assignment and declaration.
If I were to implement this in a class...

```py
class Foo:
    num = Decriptor(field_type=int)
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.z = num
```

Objective: How do I take the name of the variable num as a string without direct reference and assign it to a field in the Descriptor class, say `self.name`? So when I change the values in different instances of the class, I can just write `instance.__dict__[self.name] = constant`?

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.7, we have method `__set_name__`, called at initialization of descriptor that reads the name of the variable

```py
#add this to code
def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
    self.name = name
```